# 'Movie Japanese' vs Real Japanese

Tags: words

My question is: has anyone else ever experienced the following situation?

Several times I've used Japanese words or phrases that I learned from movies in actual conversations with Japanese people, but they either correct me or look confused. When I hear a word in a movie that I don't know, I assume it is something most native speakers use, so  I learn that word. For example, I learned the word 完全主義者 in a movie recently, and I tried using it in conversations with two different Japanese people. Both of them corrected me with 完璧主義者. As far as I can tell, both words essentially mean 'perfectionist'.  Of course I know that the normal word is 完璧主義者 but why would they actually correct me if both words mean the same thing?

Has this ever happened you? Do you think there is a difference between movie Japanese and real conversational Japanese?

Comment: The "movie" part might be a red herring here…

Comment: Is the question about 完璧主義 vs 完全主義 (more specifically), or about movie Japanese vs real conversational Japanese (more generally)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For example, I learned the word 完全主義者 in a movie recently, and I tried using it in conversations with two different Japanese people. Both of them corrected me with 完璧主義者.

あなたの知っている日本人が「完全主義者」を「完璧主義者」に訂正した理由は、前者がnegativeの度合いが強いからなどの理由ではないと思います。
単純に、同様の意味なら「完全主義者」と「完璧主義者」とを比べると、「完璧主義者」の方が普及しているので、あなたが使った「完全主義者」という言葉に違和感を感じて比較的聞きなれている「完璧主義者」の使用を勧めたものだと思います。

この判断において構成要素である「完璧」と「完全」の詳細な意味を比較してもあまり意味がないと思います。

因みに、「完全主義者」を調べると「完璧主義者」と同じで、その意味は「＊＊＊＊」であって、余り度が過ぎると「他人から嫌われる」のような説明になっています。

両者は単純に使用頻度の差ですので、映画と実社会との使用の比較も無意味だと思います。

質問者がperfectionistの意味で使う時には、日本人が聞きなれている「完璧主義者」の使用を勧めます。

---

## EDIT

「完全主義者」と「完璧主義者」とで、何故「完璧主義者」の方が同じperfectionistの意味として多く使われ、従って聞きなれているのか自分なりに考えてみました。

辞書等で、「完全主義」あるいは「完全主義者」の意味を調べてみますと、「完璧主義」あるいは「完璧主義者」と同じである、あるいは、「完璧」という言葉を使って説明している場合が多いが、逆の場合、すなわち、「完全主義者」で「完璧主義者」を説明しているケースは、皆無に近いことが分かります。これは、概念的に同じなら、「完璧主義」あるいは「完璧主義者」が、日本語として「完全主義」あるいは「完全主義者」に対して身近な表現として理解されていることの現れだろうと推察します。

これにより、「完璧主義者」の方が優先していることの実態はある程度分かりますが、何故「完璧主義者」の方が優先しているのかという理由にはなりません。

> この判断において構成要素である「完璧」と「完全」の詳細な意味を比較してもあまり意味がないと思います。

私の最初の回答の中で私は上のように書きました。

しかし、「完全」と「完璧」とでは、使用上で何らかの違いがあることを私自身感じていますので、この違いを明らかにすると、何故「完璧主義者」がより多く使われているのかが分かるものと思い、調べてみました。

インターネットで見つかった「[『完全』と『完璧』の違いってなんですか?](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1024890320)」のベストアンサーを見ますと次のようになっております。

> 完全とは簡単に言えば単に「100%」ということで、ポジティブなニュアンスでもネガティブなニュアンスでも使います。
> 完璧とは本来「欠点や不足が全くなく、非常に立派なさま、完全無欠、遺漏なくやってのける」の意味で、ポジティブなニュアンスのみです。

これでも、「完璧主義者」の優先度が高い理由が分かりません。

的確な答えを探せませんでしたので、私が感じている「完全」と「完璧」の違いを列記します。
これはあくまでも私見ですので、人によって理解が違うことは十分考えられます。

> #### 「完全」
>
> - 機械あるいは計測器による測定の結果、期待する数値、水準に完全に一致している。
> - 「完全」であることの判断は、ほぼ人に依らないで一致する。
> - 機械的、学問的、数学的、ディジタル的、静的、即物的である。「完全衝突⇔×完璧衝突」「完全円⇔×完璧円」「完全水平⇔×完璧水平」「完全零位置⇔完璧零位置」
>
> #### 「完璧」
>
> - 期待する状態に完全に到達していることの人による評価あるいは判断。
> - 「完璧」であることの判断は、判断する人によって変わる。ある人は「完璧」と判断しても別の人は「完璧ではない」と言うかもしれない。また、「完璧」と言った人の満足感が感じられる。
> - 情緒的、アナログ的、動的、属人的である。

実際のシーンを想定して「完全」と「完璧」のニュアンスの違いを感じていただきたいと思います。

> 上司から頼まれていた仕事がようやく完成した部下が、上司に完成品を持って終了報告に来た。
> 上司は「完全だね！」あるいは「完璧だね！」と言った。
> この場合は、「完全だね！」と言った上司は、完成した品物の完成度が非の打ちどころがないと言っているように私は感じます。一方「完璧だね！」と言った場合、完成した品物の完成度への高い評価はもちろんですが、完成品を手にした上司の満足感と、「よくやったね、ご苦労さん！」という部下に対するねぎらいの言葉もあわせて感じられます。

上記のように両者の意味は似ているかも知れませんが、ニュアンスがかなり違いますので、使われ方に大きな差が出るものと思われます。特に、perfectionistのように機械的に判断できない「人」に対する表現では、明らかに「完璧」という言葉が持っている「完全」にないニュアンスが反映される「完璧主義者」の方が自然に聞こえるのだと思われ、従って使用頻度も自ずと高くなっているものと思われます。

Comment: `その意味は「＊＊＊＊」であって、` -- すみません、「＊＊＊＊」はどういう意味の記号ですか？

Comment: @Chocolate: 因みに以下は、両者は、意味は「ほぼ同じ」であって、いずれも「度が過ぎると嫌われる」という部分だけが伝えたい文です。従って、両者の意味そのものは当たり前の内容として特別に伝える必要がなく、「＊＊＊＊」で省略しております。表現が飛躍しているようですみません。

Comment: @mackygoo 細かく説明してくれてありがとうございました。感謝しています。

Comment: @mackygoo perhaps a longer translation of each word would help? 完璧主義者 someone who always strives for the attainment of perceived perfection in their actions, 完全主義者 someone who always carries out their intended actions to total completion.

Comment: In other words, there is an element of subjective appraisal in 完璧主義者 whereas there is an objective assessment of the stage of completion in 完全主義者

Comment: @kandyman: 私の回答が日本語だったので大変苦労を掛けたようですみません。完璧主義者と完全主義者の概略の意味を英語で表現いただき感謝します。しかし、貴兄の英訳を見て、私の意図した内容が伝わっていないのだと理解しました。以下に私が意図した内容を要約して伝えます。(1) 完璧主義者と完全主義者とはperfectionistとして同様の意味であるとして理解できる。(2)しかし、「 完全主義者」という言葉は、日本人は余り聞いたことがないように思う。すなわち、聞き慣れないので日本語として変な感じがする。(3) 意味は同じなのに、何故このような違いが生じるのかを「完璧」と「完全」という言葉に限定して考えた結果、辞書には的確な説明がないので、両者に対して私が持っている感じをまとめてみた。その結果、前者は属人的、後者は即物的なニュアンスがある。(4) 従って、人の属性を表すperfectionistに相当する日本語として表現できる候補である「完璧主義者」と「完全主義者」とを比べると、「完璧」が人の属性を表すには向いているので、その単語を含む「完璧主義者」という単語の使用頻度が高くなり、結果として自然な日本語として受け取られるのだろうと推察する。

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% sure on this, but what I have researched is that it seems the use of 完全主義者 has a negative meaning. I found it used on a psychology site that used the word in reference to point out that someone suffers from an illness of perfectionism and the person is obsessive in a negative manner. The other one, (完璧主義者) from what I looked up shows more positive meaning such as you did that flawlessly.

Here is an example sentence I found: 君は完璧な仕事をしてくれた。- You've done a perfect job.

Answer (score 1):

Let 完璧 be used when one is ideal for a situation and 完全 be used when one fulfills a requirement.

I think the words can be interchangeable in the meaning. However 完全主義者 sounds referring to a really meticulous person in slightly negative way such as a person checking every procedures all the time and 完璧主義者 sounds referring to a really meticulous person in positive way such as a person trying to finish an work in detail.

I think 完璧主義者(perfectionist) is more common than the other but it’s subtle.

Comment: Interesting point. I suppose in English the word "perfectionist" could be taken to be either positive or negative, depending on the context. So are you suggesting that they corrected me because they felt I was using a negative term and they thought it would be better to be rephrased as a positive term? ie that they were being polite?

Comment: @kandyman I do think so. They didn’t want to take it negatively. Even in Japanese 完璧主義者 could be negative but they might have felt it is better than 完全主義者。

Comment: you can liken it to whether you describe someone's "perfectionist" as "meticulous and detailed" or "compulsive and OCD". one has a positive connotation, the other, not so much.

Comment: @psosuna As WildCard pointed out, I might find 完全主義者 in  psychological symptoms and the other as normal. It’s confusing a little bit. 完全 is more of complete and 完璧 is perfect. Whether OCD or not, I might see 完全主義者 as being meticulous all the time. And 完璧主義者 is simply focusing on their work.